# Date time format issue in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, c#-4.0

I am working in asp.net using c# getting this error 1292 invalid date format when writing sql simple insert query but it goes fine with entity frame work why it is giving error with sql insert query? for database using mysql and column format is datetime format.

SQL code

```
INSERT INTO `log`(`LogID`,`Time`,`Details`,`UserName`,`LogType`)
VALUES('0','6/30/2012 3:47:22 PM','testaaaa Deleted','admin','1');
```

For entity framework

```
log.AddLog();
//Where log is table object name.
```

Comment: Can you show some code or something?

Comment: Please put some code so that we can answer.

Comment: I have already mention in my question that is datetime format column

Comment: Can you not use parameters with your command object - or is that not supported with mysql?

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `STR_TO_DATE` to get MySQL to interpret your nonstandard date/time string correctly when you use SQL directly.

```
STR_TO_DATE('6/30/2012 3:47:22 PM', '%m/%e/%Y %h:%i:%s %p')
```

should do the trick for you.  Accordingly, your insert statement becomes:

```
INSERT INTO `log`
  (`LogID`,
   `Time`,
   `Details`,`UserName`,`LogType`)
VALUES
  ('0',
   STR_TO_DATE('6/30/2012 3:47:22 PM', '%m/%e/%Y %h:%i:%s %p'),
  'testaaaa Deleted','admin','1')
```

The MySQL entity framework code knows how to convert Dotnet dates to the appropriate format for MySQL code.  That's why it works correctly.

The fiddly little %m %h stuff is shown here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 2):

pretty sure you have to enter in this format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS

so try

```
INSERT INTO `log`(`LogID`,`Time`,`Details`,`UserName`,`LogType`)
VALUES('0','2012-06-30 15:47:22','testaaaa Deleted','admin','1');
```

Comment: You are right but my question was why entity framework allow to enter?

Comment: your question is `why it is giving error with sql insert query?` by not having the correct format you will get an error

Comment: my question was why it works fine with etityframe work. It should give error as it gives with insert query.

Comment: based simply on your text in your question I cannot make this assumption. when posting a question ask what you need to ask as clearly as possible. when you text says `why is giving error with sql insert query` at the end of a run on sentence i have to assume that that is your question

Answer (score -1):

There are different formats accepted for the datetime field. I'm pretty sure you can't use PM in the format you are using. You can only use 4 PM, 3 PM etc. Try removing the PM part and see if that works for you.

Answer (score -1):

I think......pls check table name..it should not be quoted in single.....only values should be in single quotes.......

Comment: table name can be quoted in singles. This is used in case you need to name your table as a reserved keyword. Example create table 'select'....